# Using JavaFX without "installing" it

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to use JavaFX's web browser in an application I am developing for a client. The problem is my client's server runs on a JDK 6 environment and it has a lot of burocracy and paper to ask him to either update Java SDK or to install JavaFX SDK as the Oracle's guide suggests. So I would like to know if there's a way to import JavaFX JAR's into my project instead of having to install it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's called a [Self Contained Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_quick_start.htm#CHDFEJBB)

Comment: @brian You should expand that into a full answer.

Comment: Thank you brian. I will gladly give you the correct answer if you expand it :)